# Android access recyclerview item without being recycled

Tags: android

I am trying to highlight some items in `RecyclerView`, I succeed doing that programmatically but when I try to highlight some of them that are not `Recycled` I get null pointer. Is there a way to recycle the item that I am highlighting with programmatically scrooling or something else ?

What I've tried so far:

```
    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position that I'm highlighting, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong is that I worried too much about setting the item in recyclerview when on my `onBindViewHolder` I already had something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);
    if(selectedItem == position){
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(40, 100, 100, 230));
    }
    else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

If the item that is marked as highlight if is not on the screen to highlight it on scrooling.

And when I am trying to highlight an item I check if position of the viewholder is null, if is not I can make the changes, if is null I wait for `recyclerView` to highlight it.

```
    mAdapter.setSelectedItem(myDataList.indexOf(name));
    if( musicList.findViewHolderForPosition(myDataList.indexOf(name)) != null ){
        musicList.findViewHolderForPosition(myDataList.indexOf(name)).itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(40, 100, 100, 230));
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```